# Double curly braces don't work

Tags: angularjs

I usually don't have this problem but for some reason I cannot make this work. I put `ng-app="LunchCheck"` in the `body` tag and when I do this

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="LunchCheckController">
     <h1>{{title}}</h1>

</div>
```

the variable `title` is not displaying. It is declared in the .js file, in the controller:

```
var LunchCheck = angular.module('LunchCheck', []);

LunchCheck.controller('LunchCheckController', 
                      LunchCheckController                     
);

LunchCheckController.$inject['$scope'];

function LunchCheckController($scope){
    $scope.title="Lunch Checker";
    $scope.count=getCount();
    $scope.message="";
    if($scope.count<=3){
        $scope.message="Enjoy!";
    }
    else $scope.message ="Too much!" ;
};
```

You can view the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n0jtbysz/). Please help me with this, thank you.

Comment: Move your `script` to `head`. Also, if you are begining to learn angular, learn angular 2, not angular 1, angular 1 will become irrelevant soon, it is slow

Comment: @Dummy I have to separate the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working: https://jsfiddle.net/suvartheec/n0jtbysz/3/

Used External Resources to load Angular and jQuery, changed body tag to

```
<body ng-app="LunchCheck">
```

Changed Load Type of Javascript to "No wrap - In Head" and commented out the script tags in the html.

Comment: in my html I actually placed the script tags within my head tags, but does not work.

Comment: the error that i was getting in console is that "angular is not defined" which would indicate that the order of initialization was wrong somewhere. The fiddle link that you posted here, it has the scripts src tags inside the body. also the body tag shouldnt be there because jsFiddle supplies the body tag and this would cause duplication.

Comment: I understand your configuration in jsfiddle. but right now in my NetBeans project, I included the libraries in the `<head>` tags (and before the `<title>` tags), in the order of jQuery -> AngularJS -> app.js, but still does not work

Comment: What error are you getting in the console? All the inline as well as external javascripts in head? And the body declaration is `<body ng-app="LunchCheck">` ?

Comment: I figured it out. Somehow I have to place `app.js` in the same folder as index.html. I will still award you the correct answer since you taught me how to use Jsfiddle.

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can place it in a different folder as well, in which case you would have to specify the location like `<script src="../folderName/app.js">`